# Validación de fechas con php

Tags: php, javascript, html

El código en general esta bien. Lo que me falla es la función para comprobar las fechas, no consigo que funcione correctamente y hay algún fallo que no consigo averiguar. Se supone que hay dos radio buttons (uno para elegir billete de ida solo y otro para elegir billete de ida y vuelta) y en función del seleccionado se habilita o deshabilita el desplegable de elección de fecha de vuelta. Hasta ahí todo bien, el tema es que al comprobar con la fun ción comprobarFechas siempre me da error cuando eligo solo billete de ida. Un saludo y gracias por atenderme.

```html
<?php
 error_reporting(0);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es-ES">
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <script type="text/javascript">
  function habilitar(value) {
   if (value == "1") {
    document.getElementById("campoVuelta").disabled = false;
   } else if(value == "2") {
    document.getElementById("campoVuelta").disabled = true;
   }
  }
 </script>
 <title>Compra-Venta Billetes</title>
</head>
<body>
 <?php
  $nombreErr = $apellidoErr = $fechaErr = $claseErr = $extrasErr = "";
  $correcto = true;

  if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
   if (empty($_POST["nombre"])) {
    $nombreErr = "Debe indicar un nombre.";
    $correcto = false;
   } else {
    if (!comprobarNombreYapellido($_POST["nombre"])) {
     $nombreErr = "Debe indicar un nombre válido. Use letras solamente.";
     $correcto = false;
    }
   }

   if (empty($_POST["apellido"])) {
    $apellidoErr = "Debe indicar un apellido.";
    $correcto = false;
   } else {
    if (!comprobarNombreYapellido($_POST["apellido"])) {
     $apellidoErr = "Debe indicar un apellido válido. Use letras solamente.";
     $correcto = false;
    }
   }

   if (empty($_POST["clase"])) {
    $claseErr = "Debe indicar una clase.";
    $correcto = false;
   }

   if (!comprobarExtras($_POST["extras"])) {
    $extrasErr = "No puede seleccionar mas de un extra de cada grupo";
    $correcto = false;
   }

   if (!comprobarFechas($_POST["ida"], $_POST["vuelta"], $_POST["trayecto"])) {
    $fechaErr = "La fecha de ida debe ser válida y la fecha de vuelta debe ser posterior a la fecha de ida.";
    $correcto = false;
   }
  }

  function comprobarFechas($fechaIda, $fechaVuelta, $trayecto) {
   /* si el campo fecha de vuelta esta vacío y el trayecto solo es de ida */
   if (empty($fechaVuelta) && $trayecto == "Solo ida") {
    /* se comprueba que la fecha de ida sea superior a la fecha actual */
    if (strtotime($fechaIda) > strtotime(date("Y-m-d"))) {
     return true;
    } else {
     return false;
    }
   /* en caso contrario hay fecha de vuelta y fecha de ida */
   } else {
    /* se comprueba si la fecha de vuelta es superior a la fecha de ida y si la fecha de ida es superior a la fecha actual */
    if (strtotime($fechaVuelta) > strtotime($fechaIda) && strtotime($fechaIda) > strtotime(date("Y-m-d"))) {
     return true;
    } else {
     return false;
    }
   }
  }

  function comprobarNombreYapellido($valor) {
   /* valida si el nombre contiene solo letras y espacios */
   if (preg_match("/^([a-z ñáéíóú]{2,60})$/i",$valor)) {
    return true;
   } else {
    return false;
   }
  }

  function comprobarExtras($extras) {
   if (empty($extras)) {
    return true;
   } else {
    $cantidadPeriodicos = 0;
    $cantidadDesayunos = 0;
    $cantidadAperitivos = 0;
    $cantidadAuriculares = 0;
    $cantidadPeliculas = 0;
    $cantidadExtras = count($extras) - 1;
    $arrayPeriodicos = ["Daily Mail", "El Mundo", "Marca"];
    $arrayDesayunos = ["Continental", "Americano", "Internacional"];
    $arrayAperitivos = ["Patatas bravas", "Ensaladilla rusa", "Embutidos", "Boquerones en vinagre"];
    $arrayAuriculares = ["Básicos", "Premium"];
    $arrayPeliculas = ["Gladiator", "Vengadores Endgame", "Titanic", "Memento", "El rey león", "Drive"];
    for ($i=0; $i <= $cantidadExtras; $i++) {
     $periodico = $extras[$i];
     if (in_array($periodico, $arrayPeriodicos)) {
      $cantidadPeriodicos += 1;
     }
    }
    for ($x=0; $x <= $cantidadExtras; $x++) {
     $desayuno = $extras[$x];
     if (in_array($desayuno, $arrayDesayunos)) {
      $cantidadDesayunos += 1;
     }
    }
    for ($z=0; $z <= $cantidadExtras; $z++) {
     $aperitivo = $extras[$z];
     if (in_array($aperitivo, $arrayAperitivos)) {
      $cantidadAperitivos += 1;
     }
    }
    for ($y=0; $y <= $cantidadExtras; $y++) {
     $auricular = $extras[$y];
     if (in_array($auricular, $arrayAuriculares)) {
      $cantidadAuriculares += 1;
     }
    }
    for ($n=0; $n <= $cantidadExtras; $n++) {
     $pelicula = $extras[$n];
     if (in_array($pelicula, $arrayPeliculas)) {
      $cantidadPeliculas += 1;
     }
    }

    if ($cantidadPeriodicos > 1) {
     return false;
    } elseif ($cantidadDesayunos > 1) {
     return false;
    } elseif ($cantidadAperitivos > 1) {
     return false;
    } elseif ($cantidadAuriculares > 1) {
     return false;
    } elseif ($cantidadPeliculas > 1) {
     return false;
    } else {
     return true;
    }
   }
  }
  /* si no valida el formulario volver a mostrarlo con los errores */
  if(!isset($_POST["botonEnvio"]) || !$correcto) {
 ?>
 <h2>Datos del viajero y el viaje</h2>
 <form method="post" action="<?php htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>">
  <label>Nombre:</label>
  <input type="text" name="nombre">
  <span><?php echo $nombreErr; ?></span>
  <br><br>
  <label>Primer apellido:</label>
  <input type="text" name="apellido">
  <span><?php echo $apellidoErr; ?></span>
  <br><br>
  <label>Trayecto:</label>
  <input type="radio" name="trayecto" value="1" onchange="habilitar(this.value);">Ida y vuelta
  <input type="radio" name="trayecto" value="2" onchange="habilitar(this.value);">Solo ida
  <br><br>
  <label>Fecha de ida:</label>
  <input type="date" name="ida">
  <br><br>
  <label>Fecha de vuelta:</label>
  <input type="date" name="vuelta" id="campoVuelta">
  <span><?php echo $fechaErr; ?></span>
  <br><br>
  <label>Clase:</label>
  <input type="radio" name="clase">Turista
  <input type="radio" name="clase">Preferente
  <input type="radio" name="clase">Business
  <span><?php echo $claseErr; ?></span>
  <br><br>
  <label>Extras</label>
  <select name="extras[]" multiple="multiple">
   <optgroup label="Periodicos">
    <option>Daily Mail</option>
    <option>El Mundo</option>
    <option>Marca</option>
   </optgroup>
   <optgroup label="Desayunos">
    <option>Continental</option>
    <option>Americano</option>
    <option>Internacional</option>
   </optgroup>
   <optgroup label="Aperitivos">
    <option>Patatas bravas</option>
    <option>Ensaladilla rusa</option>
    <option>Embutidos</option>
    <option>Boquerones en vinagre</option>
   </optgroup>
   <optgroup label="Auriculares">
    <option>Básicos</option>
    <option>Premium</option>
   </optgroup>
   <optgroup label="Peliculas">
    <option>Gladiator</option>
    <option>Vengadores Endgame</option>
    <option>Titanic</option>
    <option>Memento</option>
    <option>El rey león</option>
    <option>Drive</option>
   </optgroup>
  </select>
  <span><?php echo $extrasErr; ?></span>
  <br><br>
  <input type="submit" name="botonEnvio" value="enviar">
 </form>
 <?php
  /* si valida el formulario carga en sesion los siguientes valores */ 
  } else {
  $_SESSION["nombre"] = $_POST["nombre"];
  $_SESSION["apellido"] = $_POST["apellido"];
  $_SESSION["ida"] = $_POST["ida"];
  $_SESSION["vuelta"] = $_POST["vuelta"];
  $_SESSION["clase"] = $_POST["clase"];
  $_SESSION["extras"] = $_POST["extras"];
  header("Location: ./2017_03_01_2ev-Ejercicio2c.php");
  }
 ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Que error te da ?

Comment: Veo muchas lagunas en tu código. Ni siquiera verificas que algo básico como `$_POST["ida"]` y `$_POST["vuelta"]` no están vacíos. Empieza por ahí, mostrándonos lo que hay en  `var_dump($_POST);` El código hay que mejorarlo bastante, es demasiado *verboso* y puedes simplificar muchos procesos si te lo propones y te decides a optimizarlo. Pero empecemos por lo primero: **depura lo que hay en el POST** y dinos con qué datos estamos trabajando para poder ayudarte.